# How to write multiple pages with same parameters in .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, backend

I am having 2 pages (page1.php , page2.php) taking 2 parameters along with them in the URL.

```
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)?$ page1.php?page=$1&detail=$2

RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)?$ page2.php?type=$1&val=$2
```

The above code is creating error while redirecting. Can anybody tell what is the right **Rule** ?

Comment: Could you please be clear which url should be served by page1.php and which one should serve by page2.php file?

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ /page1.php?page=$1&detail=$2

RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ /page2.php?type=$1&val=$2
```

I think you were missing just a few `/`